# how to fix a response entity object returning null in its body

Tags: java, spring, http, resttemplate

How to fix a rest template object returning null in the body

```
ResponseEntity<List<Spot>> reEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<Spot>>(HttpStatus.OK);
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Spot>> parameterizedTypeReference =  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Spot>>() {
        };
List<Spot> spots = new ArrayList<Spot>(); //initialized
resEntity.getBody().addAll(spots);//getBody() is  returning null
```

Comment: could you show how you initialize `spots` variable?

Comment: @itwasntme i have updated and shown

Answer (score 1):

You should define the body on this line

```
ResponseEntity<List<Spot>> reEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<Spot>>(HttpStatus.OK);
```

like this next line

```
ResponseEntity<List<Spot>> reEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<Spot>>(spots, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I would even suggest you to use ResponseEntity builder like following

```
ResponseEntity.ok(spots);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Did what to write for the second line having  ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Spot>> parameterizedTypeReference =  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Spot>>() {
        };

Comment: where do you need to use parameterizedTypeReference?
what's the reason for its existence?

Comment: the way it is now declared and initialized it's not used anywhere